# Not able to update columns of a table by bind parameters using sql developer

Tags: sql, binding, oracle-sqldeveloper

The following select statement returns one row:

```
SELECT *
FROM CM_APOLLO_DET
WHERE
    CM_APOLLO_DET.DETAIL_ID = TRIM(:detailId) AND
    CM_APOLLO_DET.HEADER_ID IN (SELECT HEADER_ID FROM CM_APOLLO_HDR
                                WHERE TRIM(FILE_NAME) = TRIM(:fileName));
```

Values of bind parameters are as follows:

```
detailId: 775686609762
filename:sample3.txt
```

but when I run following update statement, it updates zero rows.

```
UPDATE CM_APOLLO_DET
SET CM_APOLLO_DET.DIVISION = :div
WHERE
    CM_APOLLO_DET.DETAIL_ID = TRIM(:detailId) AND
    CM_APOLLO_DET.HEADER_ID IN (SELECT HEADER_ID FROM CM_APOLLO_HDR
                                WHERE TRIM(FILE_NAME) = TRIM(:fileName));

div=2030
detailId: 775686609762
filename:sample3.txt
```

This update where condition is same as above select statement.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be reproducible, and I question your data, and whether it were really the same when you ran the select and update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using exists

```
update CM_APOLLO_DET set CM_APOLLO_DET.DIVISION=:div 
where CM_APOLLO_DET.DETAIL_ID=trim(:detailId) and 
exists (SELECT 1 from 
   CM_APOLLO_HDR where CM_APOLLO_DET.HEADER_ID=CM_APOLLO_HDR.HEADER_ID  
   and trim(FILE_NAME)=trim(:fileName)
);
```

Comment: Why would you expect this to work, or to have a different result from what the OP is seeing?